# With React-Router 4, how to define a default path based on Authentication State

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

my current React app's router looks like this:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/welcome" layout={MainLayout} component={Welcome} />
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
```

PrivateRoute is from [react-devise](https://github.com/timscott/react-devise) which only works if the user is authenticated

What I need help with is when the user loads `/` in the browser, I'd like the following

**If user is not signed in:** Load component {LandingPage}

**If user is signed in:** Load component {Dashboard}

How can this be done with react-router-4?

Thanks